# Javascript to CSV Function not compatible with IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, csv, firefox

I have a function that converts data to csv using javascript. Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/qdq3vzqg/) . This however does not work in firefox or Internet explorer. I tried debugging but i am not sure what to look for or where and nothing sticks out clearly. Any help is apprecitated. Thanks

```
 <body>

 <a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "stock-data.csv" });'>Download CSV</a>

</body>

     var stockData = [
    {
        Symbol: "AAPL",
        Company: "Apple Inc.",
        Price: "132.54"
    },
    {
        Symbol: "INTC",
        Company: "Intel Corporation",
        Price: "33.45"
    },
    {
        Symbol: "GOOG",
        Company: "Google Inc",
        Price: "554.52"
    }
];

function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
    var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

    data = args.data || null;
    if (data == null || !data.length) {
        return null;
    }

    columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
    lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

    result = '';
    result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
    result += lineDelimiter;

    data.forEach(function(item) {
        ctr = 0;
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

            result += item[key];
            ctr++;
        });
        result += lineDelimiter;
    });

    return result;
}

window.downloadCSV = function(args) {
    var data, filename, link;

    var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
        data: stockData
    });
    if (csv == null) return;

    filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

    if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
        csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
    }
    data = encodeURI(csv);

    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', data);
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.click();
};
```

Comment: you should check d3.js i've use it to parse json to csv and worked quite good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download in firefox and ie you have to append it to the body before clicking. Try adding this.

```
link.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5z8uj5z/2/).

Comment: I tried editing it in the fiddle and it did not work.

Comment: @LeonardoTrimarchi Added a fiddle. Fixed a typo.

Comment: Awesome! this worked on firefox. Ie threw this error "The data area passed to a system call is too small" Thanks for your help!